# How can I listen for raw ethernet frames in vanilla Python 3?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm doing some self-educational low-level network programming in Python. I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04** and **Python 3**. Using this code, I'm able to send raw ethernet packets:

```
from socket import socket as Socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW

def send_bytes(byte_sequence):
    with Socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW) as socket:
        socket.bind(("enp0s31f6", 0))
        socket.send(bytes(byte_sequence))
```

I can use this procedure to send pings. I know it's working because I can see the ping going out and receiving a response in Wireshark.

Now I want to listen for packets, like the response to my ping. How can I do this, hopefully without involving any non-standardlib libraries? I'd like the code to be as "close to the metal" as possible, so ideally I'd like to listen for the entire ethernet frame so I can parse it all by hand and figure out if it's the packet I'm looking for.

Comment: Perhaps the python library of wireshark might be useful for you ? https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/

Comment: @roganjosh Library recommendations? I mentioned explicitly in the last paragraph (and indirectly in the title) that I don't want to use any libraries. Was my phrasing not clear?

Comment: @JackM you're right, I have retracted my vote

Answer (score 7):

This works for me

```
import sys
import socket
ETH_P_ALL=3 # not defined in socket module, sadly...
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
s.bind(("eth0", 0))
r=s.recv(2000)
sys.stdout.write("<%s>\n"%repr(r))
```

The third argument when creating the socket acts as a filter on the type of incoming frames we want to capture (all of them here).

The `ETH_P_ALL` constant comes from `/usr/include/linux/if_ether.h`.

Comment: Nice! It looks like this just gives me the full stream of all bytes coming through the interface, so I don't think it gets much more low level than this.

Comment: @JackM Yes, exactly, the ethernet frame (mac-dst, mac-src, type, ...)

Comment: So to be clear, each time I call `recv`, I get exactly one ethernet frame, right? As opposed to like the second half of one frame and the first half of the next.

Comment: @JackM yes, a bit like UDP, you get one frame/datagram at each `recv()` operation. You must just ensure that your reception buffer if large enough (14+MTU) to get the whole frame.

Comment: How can I guarantee I see all frames? If I call `recv` and it's not the packet I want, and then half a second later call `recv` again, is there not a risk I'll miss the packet I want?

Comment: @JackM I'm afraid it's another question, far beyond the initial one. I'm not certain but I think there is no buffering for the frame to be captured. There exist some *zero-copy* techniques to acquire those frames as fast a possible (I guess in order not to drop any of them).

Comment: @JackM your raw socket has its own backlog queue independent of higher-level queues and those frames are buffered there. When you issue recv() it pops them off the queue one at a time. You can verify that you don't lose packets by doing this: run your raw socket code, and at the same time run another program that uses sock_stream to process tcp packets. Modify your raw socket code to time.sleep(10) between each recv(). You'll see that it continues to pop packets off the stack long past the time the other program has finished processing the data.

Comment: @JackM ... continuing: The only time your raw socket program will miss packets is if the rx queues in the kernel are overfilled and this will show up as RcvBufErrors in /proc/net/snmp and/or Drops,Overflow,Pruned in /proc/net/netstat.