# How to reflect or echo ethernet frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about reflecting or echoing ethernet frames in python?  Ideally, with the built-in libraries and not having to add third-party libraries. Even better if this could work on OSX, Linux, and Windows.  Primarily Linux and OSX, though.

I know how to do this using IP with the socks library.  My code is.  Below for UDP

```
def reflector(server_ip, port_number):
# Reflector for the network performance test.

# Variables
client_packet_count = 0
server_packet_count = 0

# Creating a UDP Socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Binding the UDP socket to the
server_address = (server_ip, port_number)

print("DEBUG Server IP:", server_ip)
print("DEBUG Port Number:", port_number)

print("Starting NetAlly Reflector on %s port %s" % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)
while True:
    print("Waiting on NetAlly Performance Test To Start")
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(buffer_size)
    print("Received %s bytes from % s " % (len(data), address))
    client_packet_count = client_packet_count + 1
    print("Data: %s" % data)
    print("Client Packets: ", client_packet_count)

    if data:
        sent = sock.sendto(data, address)
        print("sent %s bytes back to %s" % (sent, address))
        server_packet_count = server_packet_count + 1
        print("Server Packets: ", server_packet_count)
```

Comment: In this question, the question has code for how to send a raw ethernet frame, and the answer has code for how to listen to raw ethernet frames: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133295/how-can-i-listen-for-raw-ethernet-frames-in-vanilla-python-3

Comment: The remaining ambiguity for me is what you mean by "reflect" the frame. If you receive an ethernet frame with a destination MAC address for your interface, and you send out the same frame, it will immediately come right back, because the destination MAC address is still you. Presumably you want to change the destination. But what should the destination be changed to?

Comment: @NickODell. Sorry, I should have clarified a bit better.  That is correct, I would like to change the destination.  It should be that of the Source